# ¿Cómo puedo trabajar con mis vistas parciales sin que interfieran entre sí en Asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Un saludo cordial:

Estoy en un proyecto en `ASP.Net` donde en mi formulario principal llamo a dos vistas parciales:

```
@Html.Action("Consultar_Descuentos")       
@Html.Action("Calcular_Precios")
```

Las cuales tienen el siguiente código:

```
     public ActionResult Consultar_Descuentos()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Consultar_Descuentos(Hotel hotel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.descuentos = hotel.consultar_descuentos();     
        }

        return PartialView();
    }

    public ActionResult Calcular_Precios() 
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Calcular_Precios(Hotel hotel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.precios = hotel.consultar_precios();
        }

        return PartialView();
    }
```

Tengo un problema con ambas vistas parciales, cuando carga mi formulario principal al inicio no hay problemas pero si oprimo por ejemplo el botón que debería llamar a mi método `[post]Consultar_Descuentos` también se ejecutará el método `[post]Calcular_Precios`.

Ambos métodos lo que hacen es guardar en un `viewbag` el resultado de sus respectivas operaciones y mostrarlo en un `textbox`, funcionan bien pero quiero que si oprimo el botón vinculado a mi vista parcial `Consultar_Descuentos` solo se ejecute el método `post` de dicha vista.

Espero que haya podido explicarme bien, soy nuevo en `ASP.NET MVC` y hay tantas cosas que debo aprender que no sé ni por donde empezar. Agradecería un poco de orientación para que mis vistas parciales no interfieran entre sí.

Actualización:

Mi llamada a las vistas parciales no utiliza Javascript, simplemente las llamo tal como lo he puesto al inicio. Lo que quiero lograr es tener mi formulario principal "A" con dos vistas parciales "B" y "C". Tanto la vista "B" como la "C" tienen un botón y un textbox de solo lectura que mostrará un resultado cuando oprima el botón correspondiente, mi problema es que si oprimo cualquiera de los botones tanto de la vista parcial B como de la C se ejecutan ambas.

A continuación muestro mi formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se ve muy bien pero la imagen muestra mis dos vistas parciales "Consultar Descuentos" y "Calcular Precios", si oprimo cualquier botón es como si apretara ambos.

¿Cómo normalmente debería trabajar con este tipo de casos?

Estoy leyendo algo de Jquery pero hasta ahora lo que he visto solo es ideal para cargar grillas o datos que no se modificarán con la acción de un botón, simplemente muestran información.

P.D: Gracias por los videos, me tomaré el tiempo para revisarlos.

Actualización # 2:

El código de mis vistas:

```html
@model _6_Hotel.Models.Hotel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Recepcion", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true);
    <h4>Consultar descuentos   </h4>
    <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="btn_consultar_descuentos" value="Buscar" />
        &nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="txt_descuentos" value=@ViewBag.descuentos readonly />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
}
```

```html
@model _6_Hotel.Models.Hotel


@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Recepcion", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true);
    <h4>Calcular precios   </h4>
    <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.reserva.Ruc, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.reserva.Ruc, new { @id = "txt_ruc" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.reserva.Ruc)
        &nbsp;
        Tipo de pieza
        @{
                                     List<SelectListItem> lista_piezas = new List<SelectListItem>();
                                     lista_piezas.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Simple", Value = "Simple", Selected = true });
                                     lista_piezas.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Doble", Value = "Doble" });
                                     lista_piezas.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Matrimonial", Value = "Matrimonial" });
        }
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.tipo_pieza, lista_piezas)
        <br />
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.reserva.Noches, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.reserva.Noches, new { @id = "txt_noches" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.reserva.Noches)        
        &nbsp;
        <input type="submit" name="btn_calcular_precios" value="Calcular" />
        <input type="text" name="txt_precio" value=@ViewBag.precios readonly />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español y al mundo del desarrollo de aplicaciones Web con `ASP.net MVC`.

Por lo visto en tu pregunta, el problema está en cómo lo está llamando a las vistas parciales: agradecería que actualices la pregunta con las todas las vistas implicadas, en especial donde está el `JavaScript` que hace la llamada. Ningún método parece estar con un `RedirectToAction` por lo tanto es inexistente un cruce de información entre controladores.

De las buenas prácticas de `ASP.net MVC` puedo decirte que las vistas comienzan con el prefijo "_", es decir, podrían llamarse "_Consultar_Descuentos" y "_Calcular_Precios" de tal manera que mantienes la "*convención de nombres*" utilizados en aplicaciones de este tipo. Y para que se renderize correctamente, en el controlador se define de esta manera:

```
public ActionResult Calcular_Precios() 
    {
        return PartialView("_Calcular_Precios");
    }
```

Con respecto a cómo aprender sobre ASP.net MVC, te dejo unos enlaces:

- [Episodio 6 - Técnicas de estudio de la programación](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUzd8itXfOk)
- [Workshop ASP.net MVC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY)
- [Cursos en la Microsoft Virtual Academy](https://mva.microsoft.com/search/SearchResults.aspx#!q=asp.net%20mvc&index=2&lang=1033$1034)

PD: Actualizaré la respuesta tan pronto como vea la pregunta con la información solicitada

**Actualización**

Hay diversas maneras de las cuales puedes llegar a desarrollar lo que andas buscando, aquí te detallo una haciendo uso de la librería **jquery.unobtrusive-ajax** que puedes instalarlo mediante el manejador de paquetes de `Nuget`. Otra manera es realizar `AJAX` mediante eventos OnChange, OnKeyUp, OnKeyPress, OnClick (por citar ejemplos) y dibujar el `HTML` en el `DIV` definido.

Asegúrate tener **jquery.unobtrusive-ajax** En el archivo: *App_Start\BundleConfig.cs*

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"));
```

Para completar que el archivo de unobtrusive esté correctamente instalador, verifica que lo estás llamando en la vista general o en el **layout**:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Reemplaza :

```
@Html.Action("Consultar_Descuentos")       
@Html.Action("Calcular_Precios")
```

Por:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("Consultar_Descuentos");}
@{Html.RenderPartial("Calcular_Precios");}
```

Con respecto a las vistas, hice un pequeño ejemplo para que te sirva como guía:

La vista **Calcular_Precios:**

```
@using EjemploStackOverflowES.Models
@model Hotel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Calcular_Precios", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "resultadoPrecios", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true);
    <div id="resultadoPrecios">
        <h4>Calcular precios   </h4>
        <div style="border: 1px solid black;">

            <br />
            Nombre del hotel: @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Nombre)
            <input type="submit" name="btn_calcular_precios" value="Calcular" />

            <br />
            <br />
            @ViewBag.precios
        </div>
    </div>
                }
```

La vista **Consultar_Descuentos**:

```
@using EjemploStackOverflowES.Models
@model Hotel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Consultar_Descuentos", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "resultadoDescuentos", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{
    <div id="resultadoDescuentos">
        <h4>Consultar descuentos   </h4>
        <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
            Nombre del hotel: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nombre)
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="btn_consultar_descuentos" value="Buscar" />           
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
        @ViewBag.descuentos
    </div>
}
```

**Controlador**

```
  public ActionResult Consultar_Descuentos()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Consultar_Descuentos(Hotel hotel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.descuentos = "Su descuento es del 10% - " + DateTime.Now + " " + hotel.Nombre;
        }

        return PartialView();
    }

    public ActionResult Calcular_Precios()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Calcular_Precios(Hotel hotel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.precios = "Su precio es de S/.20 - " + DateTime.Now + " " + hotel.Nombre;
        }

        return PartialView();
    }
```

**Modelo**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace EjemploStackOverflowES.Models
{
    public class Hotel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**El resultado**

Se puede dar click en cualquier de los botones y lo único que se va a refrescar es el área esperada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Primero que nada, gracias por la cálida bienvenida.

Comment: de nada mi estimado, me refería al código que tienes en las vistas, por lo que veo algo me dice que tienes un solo Formulario y ambos botones están como submits.

Comment: Es un solo formulario pero llamo a dos vistas parciales cada una con un botón submit, quizás ese sea el problema estoy usando las vistas de una forma incorrecta pero debe existir una forma para lograr mi objetivo. De todas formas ya expandí un poco mas mi explicación inicial. Voy a subir el código de mis vistas

Comment: Me parece perfecto, voy actualizando la respuesta :D

Comment: Te agradezco mucho tanto el tiempo invertido como lo detallado de tu respuesta, me ha sido muy útil. En serio, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: De nada mi estimado, dale con todo el power 2.0! Recuerda aceptar a la respuesta que mejor solucione tu pregunta. . La cantidad de respuestas aceptadas juegan a favor, así salimos de la versión Beta de StackOverflow en Español. Saludos :D